# Should I use jquery or jquery mobile or iPad web pages?

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

I am making a web page "app" for the iPad or ios devices.  Should I use jquery mobile or just regular jquery?  After all they're only web pages aren't they?  Is jquery proper no good for me?  Do I need mobile jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look into two frameworks. Both are open source unless you are incorporated them into your own framework and offering this up as a service or an API.

These frameworks are [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

**Sencha Touch** is great. It looks fantastic, is an official release (out of beta unlike JQMobile), and pretty easy to use. Everything is created through Javascript, which is then rendered behind the scenes into the proper HTML/CSS. It's got great documentation, a good forum of users.

Downsides - it's only completely customizable after learning SASS/Compass.

**JQuery Mobile** is awesome as well. Everything is created using HTML5 attributes, and then the library runs over the HTML you create and renders everything properly. Very easy to use as well, and easy to customize.

Downsides - Doesn't look as nice (yet), and is still in beta (or might even be alpha?)

Comment: Just to add a bit to this great answer - the reason to use one of these frameworks (or others, such as Telerik's KendoUI Mobile) is that they handle different events and other oddities that are presented on touch devices such as iOS and Android devices - regular jQuery may work but isn't optimized with these devices in mind. SenchaTouch, jQMobile et. al. are.

Comment: Sencha touch is great, but I personally wouldn't use it for a massive complex solution.  Maybe it's the version of the framework we're using or possibly poorly written code I've inherited when I came onboard, but the app lags horribly.  Small apps with a few screens seem great with it.

Comment: @slandau Learning SASS isn't a downside..  Sass is awesome..!!!  Everyone should learn it..  What is a downside is the way that you have to compile it for Sencha on a PC..  Sass in itself is great, but getting the includes to work and compile is painful.  maybe on a mac it's easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use jQuery Mobile library. It was developed specifically for this purpose. The base jQuery library does not help you write mobile applications in and of itself.

Also look at Sencha Touch. It's a bit more mature.

Comment: On Sencha is there a difference between commercial and open source?

Comment: In terms of licensing yes, but I believe both are fully featured (and free).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery and jQuery mobile should not be considered 'mutually exclusive'. They serve very different purposes. JQM is a system for rendering mobile-friendly pages and widgets as well as handling things like touch screen events. It's strengths lie really in the GUI side of things. jQuery itself is a framework for creating triggers based on the DOM, manipulating the DOM and handling things like AJAX in a nice, cross-browser fashion. Often, if you're building anything other than a basic/static web app, you'll want to use jQuery AND JQM together.
It would be more appropriate to compare JQM to jQuery UI in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **yes**. One of the main selling points of jQuery mobile is it's touch optimized UI, and the iPad would make heavy use of that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

While jQuery Mobile has the 'jQuery' tag in it, it feels quite a lot different to me than 'normal' jQuery. 
What jQuery Mobile helps you with is setting up pages for mobile devices easily (with html data-attributes) and handling the touch and swipe events for you. You write the mark-up, and jQuery Mobile turns it into a mobile webpage. That's something 'normal' jQuery won't do for you. You do need it if you wish to use jQuery for mobile development.

It's still in alpha and has quite some little bugs and annoyances, but I would still recommend it. It's good enough to use for production settings if you manage to work out these little annoyances.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile helps you out by adding events like swipe and touch hold etc. So if you want the touch capabilities to be integrated into your web page, mobile makes it easier. Caution though, I think it is still beta.

EvoD